# Button overlaps on different resolutions

Tags: css

I made a button using this css code:

```
 div {display: inline-block, 
    width: 120px, 
    height: 40px, 
    background-color: #2e6cd1, 
    line-height:39px, 
    vertical-align: text-middle, 
    text-align: center, 
    color: #ffffff, 
    font-family: Arial, 
    font-size: 20px, 
    font-weight: bold, 
    font-style: normal, 
    border-radius: 2px, 
    opacity: 0.9, 
    left: 160px, 
    top: 300px, 
    position: absolute}`
```

For my resolution(1366x768) it fits perfectly but for others it overlaps another div or moves it away. How do I fix this?

Comment: Yoe need to use media-queries http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning. Nothing can flow naturally based on window size.

Answer (score 0):

If you use absolute positioning you always risk elements overlapping on different resolutions, as they are removed from the page flow. Use positioning that respects page flow (I mostly use relative as static does not allow setting left right top and bottom properties).